# angularjs - $http reading json and wait for callback

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to read data from json and wait until data will be fetched into $scope.urls.content. So I write code:

```
$scope.urls = { content:null};
$http.get('mock/plane_urls.json').success(function(thisData) {
    $scope.urls.content = thisData;    
});
```

And now I am trying to write something like callback but that doesn't work. How can i do that? Or is there any function for this? I am running out of ideas ;/

Comment: What you wrote already contains a callback. Explain what you're trying to achieve please.

Comment: What you see in networking tab of dev tools, do you ever have response from server ? is it with code 20x ? You are only defining success call back, which means it won't be fired in case of failure.

Comment: I am trying to use data what was fetched into $scope.urls.content but every time when i try use it immediately they have null.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that ?

```
$http.get('mock/plane_urls.json').success(function(thisData) {
    $scope.urls.content = thisData;
    $scope.yourCallback();
});
$scope.yourCallback = function() {
   // your code
};
```

Comment: I'm sure that `yourCallBack` would take a parameter of the returned data :).

Comment: I believe it should be better to use promise API instead of calling a callback directly. It was designed for these needing..

Answer (score 1):

You want to work with [promises](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) and [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

As `$http` itself returns a promise, all you got to do is to chain to its return. Simple as that:

```js
var promise = $http.get('mock/plane_urls.json').then(function(thisData) {
  $scope.urls.content = thisData;
  return 'something';
});

// somewhere else in the code
promise.then(function(data) {
  // receives the data returned from the http handler
  console.log(data === "something");
});
```

I made a pretty simple fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/uHvnR/).

But if you need to constantly call this info, you should expose it through a service, so anyone can grab its result and process it. i.e.:

```
service('dataService', function($http) {
  var requestPromise = $http.get('mock/plane_urls.json').then(function(d) {
    return d.data;
  });

  this.getPlanesURL = function() {
    return requestPromise;
  };
});

// and anywhere in code where you need this info
dataService.getPlanesURL().then(function(planes) {
  // do somehting with planes URL
  $scope.urls.content = planes;
});
```

Just an important note. This service I mocked will cache and always return the same data. If what you need is to call this JSON many times, then you should go with [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).